# Change RGB image to Grayscale while keeping the pixels values?

Tags: python, image-processing, annotations

I have an annotated RGB image in python that represents three classes:0,1,2 (annotated through labelme):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img= Image.open('image.png')
np.unique(img) # returns array([0, 1, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

**I tried converting to grayscale, but I am loosing the classes (0,1,2):**

```
from PIL import Image
img= Image.open('Image.png').convert('L')#returns an image object that contains 0,38,75 pixel values
np.unique(img) # returns array([ 0, 38, 75], dtype=uint8)
img.save('Image_converted.png')
```

**I tried using scipy, same values generated:**

```
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread('image.png', mode="L")
np.unique(img) # returns array([ 0, 38, 75], dtype=uint8)
misc.imsave('Image_converted.png',img)
```

How I would be able to convert it to grayscale keeping only three classes (0,1,2) ?

Comment: I dont understand how you convert to grayscale and still have 3 color channels in your matrix

Comment: can you show image results?

Comment: Its not having three color channels, but the generated pixel values became 0,38 or 75. I want to make them 0,1,2

Comment: Maybe if you shared the image we could help - it's hard to improve things you can't see...

Comment: Hello? Have you abandoned this question?

Comment: I found a code snippet that attempts to change RGB colors to classes, that can overcome my issue (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-deeplab-in-tensorflow-for-object-segmentation-using-deep-learning-a5777290ab6b). But I am also seeking other recommendations.

Comment: So are you going to share the image so we can try to help?